# Верно ли технически использовать одну и ту же папку как локальный репозиторий и папку проекта?

Tags: git, контроль-версий, репозиторий

Во многих интегрированных средах разработки нельзя обычным способом сделать одну и ту же папку локальным репозиторием (например, git-репозиторием) и проектной папкой (сейчас не важно, о каких именно проектах идёт речь - это может быть и сайт, и приложение на любом языке программирования). Но всё уже удобнее, когда и репозиторий, и проект в одной корневой папке, тем более что если вложить в папку репозитория проектную папку, то древо проекта, которое есть во многих IDE, может не дать доступа вовне корневого каталога проекта. Кроме того, `readme`-файл обычно кладётся в корень репозитория, а не проекта (если не совпадают), а его тоже хотелось бы реадктировать в среде.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. В моей вселенной локальный репозиторий можно создать почти где угодно, хоть в `/`, хоть прямо в ``C:\``. (Ну, в /proc/ не выйдет).

Comment: "обычным способом" – а какой способ для вас является обычным?

Comment: Ну, например, в `NetBeans` под обычным способом я подразумеваю создание нового проекта через мастер создания нового проекта. Если Вы в `NetBeans ` в меню выберете "Инициализировать Git-репозиторий", а затем начнёте создавать какой-нибудь проект, то `NetBeans` обязательно создат проектную папку внутри той, которой вы укажете.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu не вижу в тегах netbeans :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

создать файл/каталоги **внутри** git-хранилища (иначе — git-репозитория), т.е. в каталоге с именем (по умолчанию) `.git`, конечно можно:

```
$ touch .git/file
```

но вот контроль версий этого файла программа *git* (по умолчанию) вам сделать не даст:

```
$ git add .git/file
error: Invalid path '.git/file'
error: unable to add .git/file to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

потому лучше храните файлы рабочего каталога (*working directory*) отдельно: по умолчанию — в том же каталоге, где находится и каталог с хранилищем.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Я не имел ввиду папку `.git`, я имеел ввиду ротительскую папку по отношению к каталогу `.git`. Спрошу так: если папка `.git` будет среди файлов проекта, то есть внутри проектной папки, это будет нормально? (`ProjectFolder/.git`)

Comment: да, это нормально и именно так и делает программа *git* по умолчанию: файл/каталоги, историю которых вы отслеживаете, обычно располагаются в том же каталоге, где находится и само хранилище (т.е., подкаталог `.git`)

Comment: Ясно! Тогда теперь буду так делать! Ещё раз спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Александр, а вы не собираетесь баллотироваться на выборах? Я помню, как вы упорно и методично разгребали очереди проверок и списки неотвеченных. Нам сейчас как раз нужен такой человек.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6114/?noredirect=1#comment23569_6114

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ага, понял. Это досадно, я бы за вас проголосовал. Как вам новая работа?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, положительно.